# cakephp 1.3 internationalization

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, internationalization

I am having problem with cakephp 1.3.17 localization. the problem is, it can translate everything correctly except setFlash messages
I applied everything that explained on the [cakephp documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Internationalization-Localization.html) as I said before everything working fine labels,text but no error messages 
here is an example of using setFlash message

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Your service has been changed successfully',true),'success');
```

did anyone have same problem before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing special about localizing Flash messages in CakePHP 1.3.  The only things I can think of that may be your problem is if your strings aren't in the proper .po file, or you may need to delete your cache, since I believe CakePHP does save the localized strings there.

Comment: thanks for quick response. yes I think you are right about the string in the po file because on some stage I started to get this error message when I update po file `The catalog couldn't be saved in 'iso-8859-1' charset as
specified in catalog settings. It was saved in UTF-8 instead
and the setting was modified accordingly.` and some of the translations started not changing but the funny thing message that not changing is setFlash message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for the future reference if someone has the same problem, the solution in my case is I was checking the language session in beforeRender function in this case setFlash messages was already set for the language so it couldnt be changed when I add set_language function to beforeFilter in the app_controller.php it started to work. thank you for your interest